# How to execute ipdb.set_trace() at will while running pytest tests

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest for my test suite. While catching bugs in complex inter-components test, I would like to place `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in the middle of my code to allow me to debug it.

However, since pytest traps sys.stdin/sys.stdout ipdb fails. How can I use ipdb while testing with pytest.

I'm not interested in jumping to pdb or ipdb after a failure, but to place breaks anywhere in the code and be able to debug it there before the failure occurs.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

The error is raised because pytest captures output by default.

You can run pytest with `-s` option (turn off capture output). For example:

```
py.test -s my_test.py
```

and then in `my_test.py`:

```
import ipdb;
ipdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: In case one wants to do this in Django, add `addopts = -s` to `pytest.ini` file.

Answer (score 74):

pytest-ipdb is unfortunately not supported anymore.

The solution is to run 
`pytest my_test.py --pdb --pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb`

From the help command:

```
pytest -h
  --pdb                 start the interactive Python debugger on errors.
  --pdbcls=modulename:classname
                        start a custom interactive Python debugger on errors.
                        For example:
                        --pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:TerminalPdb
```

The difference is just that TerminalPdb seems to throw erros, but Pdb not ([Ipython docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/generated/IPython.core.debugger.html#IPython.core.debugger.Pdb)).

Comment: `TerminalPdb` is working again and the preferred solution as it will give you tab completion.

Comment: look out for ppdb, its got ipython quality introspection

Answer (score 9):

As of **2019-11** here is what should fix it:

```
pip install ipdb gnureadline ptpython

export PYTEST_ADDOPTS='--pdb --pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb'
```

Comment: if you install `prompt-toolkit`  version `2.0.10` then ipdb will work fine again, because it breaks due to recent update of this package to 3.0.0

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use

`py.test tests/ --pdbcls=IPython.core.debugger:Pdb -s`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give `pdbpp` a try.  I've had more success with it, compared to `ipdb` when used with `pytest`.  See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69320311/2896799.