# BdbQuit raised when debugging Python with pdb

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, pdb, ipdb

Recently when adding the `pdb` debugger to my Python 2.7.10 code, I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/isaachess/Programming/vivint/Platform/MessageProcessing/vivint_cloud/queues/connectors/amqplib_connector.py", line 191, in acking_callback
    callback(message.body)
  File "/Users/isaachess/Programming/vivint/Platform/MessageProcessing/vivint_cloud/queues/consumable_message_queue.py", line 32, in deserialized_callback
    self._callback_method(msg)
  File "/Users/isaachess/Programming/vivint/Platform/BusinessLogic/businesslogic/util/statsd_util.py", line 95, in _time_func
    retVal = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/isaachess/Programming/vivint/Platform/MessageProcessing/vivint_cloud/net/router.py", line 226, in handle
    try:
  File "/Users/isaachess/Programming/vivint/Platform/MessageProcessing/vivint_cloud/net/router.py", line 226, in handle
    try:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 49, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 68, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
BdbQuit
```

This is after inserting the line:

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

in the code.

I cannot figure out why this is happening. I've read up on Bdb and Bdbquit, but cannot figure out why this is happening in my code. Can anyone provide me with some hints of why this happens in general? I *really* want to get the debugger working again.

Comment: How do you run your process? My guess is that your process is not attached to a terminal or something like that. Is this a subprocess or something like that?

Comment: @shx2, subprocess? Could somehow the use of [Luigi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/luigi) cause this?

Comment: I encountered [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453619/pdb-crashed-cannot-set-breakpoint). Really hope it could be resolved

Answer (score 27):

I ran into this when I left `import pdb` and a `pdb.set_trace()` in my production code. When the `pdb.set_trace()` line was executed, python was waiting for my input to tell it to `c`ontinue or step into, etc... Because the python code was being called by a web server I wasn't there to press `c` to continue. After so long (not sure how long) it finally raised the `BdbQuit` exception.

I didn't have anything setup to catch that exception so it raised a 500 in my web server.

It took me a while to understand that my debug code running in an a daemon/background was causing the issue. I felt silly.

Comment: Updated my answer to whoever down voted. If you down voted, please do re read answer and leave an explanation as to why this is not answering the question.

Comment: How exactly did you do it then?

Comment: @AbhishekRai Are you trying to run PDB in production? I think what you need to do is not run that in production and remove the pdf.set_trace() from your code.

Comment: still don't understand..how to debug it then?

Answer (score 18):

If you continue from the `(pdb)` prompt and allow your code to finish normally, I wouldn't expect output like the traceback you indicated, but if you quit `pdb`, with the `quit` command or ^D (EOF), a traceback like that occurs because there is nothing to catch the `BdbQuit` exception raised when the debugger quits. In `bdb.py` `self.quitting` gets set to `True` by the `set_quit` method (and by `finally` clauses in the various run methods). Dispatch methods called by `trace_dispatch` `raise BdbQuit` when `self.quitting` is `True`, and the typical `except:` clause for `BdbQuit` is a simple `pass` statement; `pdb` inherits all of that from `gdb`.

In short, exception handling is used to disable the system trace function used by the debugger, when the debugger interaction finishes early.

One way to avoid that traceback altogether is to use `pdb` differently. Rather than calling `pdb.set_trace()` from your code (and not handling `BdbQuit` at all), you can invoke your code within `pdb` (rather than vice versa), at which point the `BdbQuit` exception will be handled as intended by pdb. That will also allow you to choose breakpoint locations without modifying your code (using `pdb`'s `break` command). Or you can mix the two approaches; run your code under `pdb`, `pdb.set_trace()` calls and all, and those calls will be breakpoints that you can remove only by modifying your code.

You can invoke your code within `pdb` by using the `pdb` command with your script invocation as its command line arguments, or with `python -m pdb`.

Comment: it would be great if you could specify possible causes of BdbQuit as pdb doesn't raise it in some scripts.

Comment: this is not the complete answer, there are many other limitations of `pdb` like it cannot work in a multiprocess pool and so on. You fail to mention those.

Comment: Running with `python -m pdb` (even in python 3.7) still hits this issue.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! This is actually what is most likely going wrong for 99% of people coming here. In my case, I was piping input to a Python process over STDIN. This causes the EOF to be immediately read by the `pdb` debugger, hence an immediate `BadQuit`.

Answer (score 17):

One possible reason is that you are running the Python script in the background. When a process runs in the background, you can't send input to the process via terminal and hence pdb console can't work. Eventually, it raises `BdbQuit`.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from Eirik Fuller answer I would like to add that you can't be using `pdb` in something thats running in a different process. For debugging you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23654936/7806805 but it seems very hackish or you can make your program run in a single thread. Consult the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html. For multiprocessing issues you might even want to go through https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/46x9sm/why_is_pdbset_trace_crashing_whenever_it_is_in_an/

Anyways your question lacks much needed context. Please add on to your question.

Answer (score 3):

you can use comand `docker-compose run --rm --service-ports {YOUR_CONTAINER}`
after added:

```
def your_f():
    **import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()**
    result = your_logic
    return result
```

exmaple:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! But instead of container name I used compose service name and without `--service-ports`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue when piping data into my script. It seems `pdb` doesn't want to hold the pipe open so it throws `BdbQuit`. I fixed the issue by saving my `stdin` data into a temp file and then reading the temp file from python.

**Before**

```
$ pbpaste | script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Code/script.py", line 78, in <module>
    process(args)
  ... blah blah ...
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/bdb.py", line 88, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/bdb.py", line 113, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
```

**After**

```
$ pbpaste > temp.txt
$ python3 script.py test.txt 
> /Users/admin/Code/script.py(49)f()
-> hello = "world"
(Pdb)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you running into this with Django tests, it can be caused by passing the `--parallel` flag to the test command. This is due to multiprocessing, as pointed out in previous replies. Try removing that flag to see if it solves the problem, it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

We need to enable shell input for the docker service that runs Django. If you're using docker compose, add: `stdin_open: true` in your docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ...
  django_app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    stdin_open: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had more luck using `pdbpp`, which is a drop in replacement for `pdb`, i.e. in doesn't require anything else than being itself (no plugin, no extra configuration/options). It supports autocompletion, which is what I was after with `ipdb`.

You can install it with `pip install pdbpp`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when there was a `breakpoint()` call left in my code. It is pretty similar to other causes raised here (various uses of `pdb`). Just know that this is also a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal solution found [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74225357)

The tldr; verison of it is put `sys.stdin = open(0)` before `pdb.set_trace()`

However note, that idfyou `set_trace` before from the main process and step with it into a breakpoint in the other process, you will create a race condition wrt. the input/stdin, i.e. part of the input will go to one process, the other part to the other process.
So don't step or next when in the main process until you reach the other breakpoint.