# How to make a pdb set_trace the first breakpoint

Tags: python, pdb

I have pdb.set_trace() in two spots of my code. The problem is that I get multiple stops in the second area when I want it to start somewhere specific. Here is an example:

```
def function():
   #some code in here
   pdb.set_trace()
   #some more code

def main():
   #some code
   function()

   #come more code
   function()

   #the code I care about
   pdb.set_trace()
   function()
```

The problem here is that it will stop in function twice before actually getting to the actual set_trace I want to which first stops inside main and then to function.

This isn't a big deal but in a real setting I get 100s of calls to inside of 'function' before getting to the 'main' set_trace(). Is there a way to specify the first set_trace() or ignore all calls to set_trace until I get to the one I want?

Comment: can you not have an `if` block with a conditional to call the set_trace ?

Answer (score 0):

You need not modify your code (by adding calls to `pdb.set_trace()`) in order to debug it with `pdb` (the advice to do that has always seemed misguided to me). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34914704/5384908) is another example of a problem this approach can cause.

If you invoke `pdb` on a version of your code with no calls to `pdb.set_trace()` and use `pdb`'s `break` command to set breakpoints wherever you might otherwise have added calls to `pdb.set_trace()`, you can use `pdb`'s `disable` command when you no longer want a breakpoint to take effect.