# How to run pdb inside a Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, pdb

I clearly don't understand something here.  I am trying to run the `pdb` debugger interactively w/in a Docker Container.

Here is some code:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PROJECT_DIR=/opt/foo
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "foo.py"]
```

**foo.py:**

```
def hello_world():
    print("hello world")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    hello_world()
```

If I run `docker build -t foo .` and then `docker run foo`, it prints out "hello world" as expected.

But if I uncomment out the call to `pdb.set_trace()` above and try again, I get the following error:

```
/opt/foo/foo.py(8)<module>()
-> hello_world()
(Pdb) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    hello_world()
  File "foo.py", line 8, in <module>
    hello_world()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 51, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_line(frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 70, in dispatch_line
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
```

What am I not getting?

---

**edit:**
[BbdQuit raised when debugging python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914704/bdbquit-raised-when-debugging-python) is *not* a duplicate issue.

My issue, as @soundstripe correctly identified, was not providing interactive access w/in Docker for pdb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bdbquit raised when debugging python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914704/bdbquit-raised-when-debugging-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`pdb` expects a usable terminal with a TTY. You can run pdb easily by telling Docker to attach an interactive TTY in the container to your terminal with `-it`:

`docker run -it foo`

I usually also add the `--rm` option to remove my temporary containers.

`docker run -it --rm foo`

But that is not always best during debugging as the container is gone when you are done.

Answer (score 25):

The tip from soundstripe did not work for me. However you can open a new terminal and type in

```
docker attach [container_name]
```

Now you should be able to use pdb.

You may need to add these to the service definition in your docker-compose yml file to make this work:

```
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Comment: I have been looking everywhere for a way to run pdb from a container started from compose. This works! 
Add pdb line where needed. start compose with -d option. attach to the needed container.

Comment: To get out of the TTY when you have hit the breakpoint press `Ctrl`+`P` and then `Ctrl`+`Q`. **Do not** use `Ctrl`+`C`, it will kill the process.

Comment: Adding to @Jonathan's answer, If you are doing ```docker-compose up``` in cmd then do ```docker attach container_id ``` only in cmd. It'll work

Comment: You'r ass keeper)))thanks, bro